# Apache CXF java.lang.StackOverflowError

Tags: java, apache, web-services, soap, cxf

Something goes wrong in my code at runtime. I implemented SOAP client using apache CXF. I created the endpoint via `JaxWsProxyFactoryBean`. Here is my code:

```
JaxWsProxyFactoryBean factory = new JaxWsProxyFactoryBean();
          factory.setServiceClass(MYAPI.class);
          factory.setAddress(service);
          api = (MYAPI) factory.create();
```

First time when I implemented it, it worked well, so I decided to do some refactoring, (move stub classes in different package, API interface in another and, so on...) When I built it again and run it, something wrong happens. The application fail's with `java.lang.StackOverflowError` at `api = (MYAPI) factory.create();` Here is the stackTrace:

```
Thread [main] (Suspended (exception StackOverflowError))    
    ReflectionUtil.getDeclaredFields(Class<?>) line: 169    
    JAXBContextInitializer.walkReferences(Class<?>) line: 395   
    JAXBContextInitializer.addClass(Class<?>) line: 317 
    JAXBContextInitializer.addType(Type, boolean) line: 236 
    JAXBContextInitializer.addType(Type) line: 226  
    JAXBContextInitializer.walkReferences(Class<?>) line: 424   
    JAXBContextInitializer.addClass(Class<?>) line: 317 
    JAXBContextInitializer.addType(Type, boolean) line: 236 
    JAXBContextInitializer.addType(Type) line: 226  
    JAXBContextInitializer.walkReferences(Class<?>) line: 424   
    JAXBContextInitializer.addClass(Class<?>) line: 317 
    JAXBContextInitializer.addType(Type, boolean) line: 236 
    JAXBContextInitializer.addType(Type) line: 226  
    JAXBContextInitializer.walkReferences(Class<?>) line: 424   
    JAXBContextInitializer.addClass(Class<?>) line: 317 
    JAXBContextInitializer.addType(Type, boolean) line: 236 
    JAXBContextInitializer.addType(Type) line: 226  
    JAXBContextInitializer.walkReferences(Class<?>) line: 424   
    JAXBContextInitializer.addClass(Class<?>) line: 317 
    JAXBContextInitializer.addType(Type, boolean) line: 236 
    JAXBContextInitializer.addType(Type) line: 226  
    JAXBContextInitializer.walkReferences(Class<?>) line: 424   
    JAXBContextInitializer.addClass(Class<?>) line: 317 
    JAXBContextInitializer.addType(Type, boolean) line: 236 
    JAXBContextInitializer.addType(Type) line: 226  
    JAXBContextInitializer.walkReferences(Class<?>) line: 424   
    JAXBContextInitializer.addClass(Class<?>) line: 317
```

....

Can anyone help me to solve this issue? I don't know what is the problem. I founded that is may be a problem to use JAVA 8 to build CXF, but I am with version 3.1.7 and I also tried to build it with Java 7, (because I don't have Java 8 specific implementations), run it and the same issue happened again.

Comment: Seems a circular reference. Could you show your JAXB model?

Comment: Do you mean, stub classes with JAXB annotations ?

Comment: Yes. It seems, that somehow a class is charging itself recursively

Comment: They are, too much (more than 100), can you suggest me, what to search for. e.g something in annotation. I am not very familiar with JAXB. CXF do it for me. Thank you for your help

Comment: Have you refactored? Go back and do it step by step. If you can't, then try to detect the service and classes that are causing the problem, for example removing service method until error is not raised.

Comment: Thank you very much. CXF generated 2 classes with the same name and the first has field that refer to the second, but after refactoring Move in another package, it became to refer to itself and because of the implementation logic it load it again and again. That was the problem, You were right! Thank you, again.

Comment: Happy to help. I posted a summary as answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(solved in comments)
It seems a circular reference where a JAXB class is charging itself recursively producing a stack overflow.

**Actions**

Have you refactored? Go back and do it step by step. If you can't, then try to detect the service and classes that are causing the problem, for example removing service method until error is not raised.

**Solution** (as  @AleydinKaraimin commented)

CXF generated 2 classes with the same name and the first has field that refer to the second, but after refactoring Move in another package, it became to refer to itself and because of the implementation logic it load it again and again.